# How do I create a "tip box"?

Tags: android, user-interface, interface

I am currently developing a magazine reader for Android. I want to have after my splashscreen some tips in order to guide the user on the way of using the app.

The picture is from the day day app, this app has the tip box that i am looking for:
[image: ...]

As you can see, the tip box is at the home layout and also indicates the number of tips (in this case three tips) at the bottom of the tip's screen.

How can I program that? Is it an specific element? How can I display it after the splashscreen?

Comment: Looks like a custom DialogFragment.

Comment: start in stages. its a custom dislog box. do you know how to do that? thats the easy part. Then its something like this https://github.com/klinker24/Android-FloatingTutorialActivity

Answer (score 1):

To get the affect of a tip bow you could try using a PopUpWindow with a custom view:

```
PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(customView, width, height, true);
```

To get the scrollable element you will need to have a ViewPager in your custom view and set up a PagerAdaptor to Scroll through each of your page Fragments.

At the bottom of the screen you will need use a group of images that change colour depending on which page of the PagerAdaptor you are on, you can do this as a part of you Adaptor.

Too display it after your SplashScreen, your best bet would be to create the window in the onCreate method of the next Activity after the SplashScreen.